# Where condition in mysql with array value

Tags: mariadb

I have a table with like this:

| id | values | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["8","7","6"] | 5 |

Now I'm running a query with `WHERE` condition on `values` column:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE values = ["8","7","6"]
```

But MySQL returns this error:

> Error Code : 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["8","7","6"]'

Comment: What's the data type of the field with the array(s)?

Comment: Please include the DDL.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` the [post the result into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67629380/edit). We want to know what is the datatype for the column `values`.

Comment: its longtext. but i stored it as a json array

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare for strict equality, you want to do the comparison as JSON objects. You can do this by using [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/) to parse the data as JSON instead of text:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE
  JSON_EXTRACT(`values`, '$') = JSON_EXTRACT('["8","7","6"]', '$');
```

You should be able to use this for any type of JSON as long as you want strict equality. If you want to return all rows that match the given JSON object, use [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/).

For example to find all values with the string `"8"` in it, you'd use the following:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`values`, '"8"');
```

Note that this matching is not as simple as you'd expect and matches any value in the document. If your data consists of JSON arrays, this should still be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

The information about your column datatype, especially `values` are crucial. Since the column stores a mix of numbers and non-numbers characters, we can assume that it might be stored in `VARCHAR()` or `TEXT` datatype. But since the data format looks like a `JSON` array, it's also a possibility that the column datatype is `JSON`. Now both of these datatypes have a very different query structure.

First, let's address some issues:

1. Whenever the cell values include other characters than numerical, it will be considered as string. Hence, using plain `.. WHERE values = ["8","7","6"]` without wrapping it in quotes (`'`), you'll get that `Error Code : 1064`.
2. `VALUES` is [a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-V) in MySQL so if you want to stick to it as your table column names, you always need to wrap it in backticks. If not, this will also return `Error Code : 1064`:

```
.. WHERE `values` = ..
```

Now let's try this:

1. If the column datatype for `values` is `VARCHAR()` or `TEXT`, you just have to simply wrap the search value in single quote like:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE `values` = '["8","7","6"]';
```

[Refer this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4450e8c7b1fc82e691027a39de2965d9)

**updated for MariaDB**

2. If the column datatype for `values` is `JSON`, it's something like this:

```
SELECT * from table_name where JSON_UNQUOTE(`values`)= '["8","7","6"]'
```

[Refer this fiddle for JSON](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1e3e6ae2995c5d26d971723f93610f79)

The JSON method I've referred to [this MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_unquote/).

P/S: According to this documentation [*JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT introduced for compatibility reasons with MySQL's JSON data type*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/). In other words, when creating a table with `JSON` datatype in MariaDB, it will be shown as `LONGTEXT` but with extra definition than just plain `LONGTEXT` datatype. [See this fiddle for more detail](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1e08a2d48682a07489e894bfac28bb97).

Comment: my values dataType is longtext.

Comment: mysql gives #1064 error when i run SELECT * from table_name 
WHERE `values`->"$[0]" = '8'
AND `values`->"$[1]" = '7'
AND `values`->"$[2]" = '6'; query

Comment: What is your exact MySQL version? Please run `SELECT @@version`. And Please post the full error message

Comment: 10.4.18-MariaDB

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>"$[0]" = '8'
AND `values`->"$[1]" = '7'
AND `values`->"$[2]" = '3'
AND `v...' at line 2

Comment: The second method can't be used with MariaDB but the first method should be fine.

Comment: First method can not give any error but also can not retrieve any row. as my datatype is not string maybe that's the reason